# Why I/O is not overlapped with computing in a multithreaded Python application?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have written a simple Python script to test overlapping between I/O-bound and cpu-bound threads. The code is here:

```
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import shutil
import os


def cpuJob(start,end):
    counter=start
    sum=0
    while counter<=end:
        sum+=counter
        counter+=1
    return sum


def ioJob(from_path, to_path):
    if os.path.exists(to_path):
        shutil.rmtree(to_path)
    shutil.copytree(from_path, to_path)

startTime=datetime.now()

Max=120000000
threadCount=2

if threadCount==1:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=cpuJob, args=(1,Max))
    # t1 = threading.Thread(target=ioJob, args=(1,Max))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
else:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=ioJob, args=("d:\\1","d:\\2"))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=cpuJob, args=(1,Max))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

endTime=datetime.now()

diffTime = endTime - startTime

print("Execution time for " , threadCount , " threads is: " , diffTime)
```

If I run the threads separately (threadCount==1), each thread takes around 12-13 seconds to be finished on my Windows laptop. But when I run them toghegher (threadCount==2), it takes around 20-22 seconds. As far as I know, Python releases the GIL before doing any blocking I/O operations. If GIL is released before working with I/O, why I get such a performance in the code?

**Edit 1:** As suggested in the commnets, I checked the code of `shutils`. It seems that in the implementation of this package, the GIL is not released. Why that is the case? The code of shell utility package should fall outside of the Python runtime implementation, No?

Comment: @iBug well, instead of shutil, I first used native Python features (file.write("sth")) for writing a huge data on a file. The results is the same.

Comment: @iBug you are right. In the source code of shutils the GIL is not released. You may write this as an answer to be accepted for this Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py` on my machine, it seems these functions `rmtree`, `copytree` etc. are implemented as Python code like `_rmtree_unsafe`. The underlying API behind `rmtree` etc. are like `os.listdir` and `os.unlink`.

Due to the restriction of [Python GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), only one thread can run Python code at a time. Therefore your `cpuJob` and `ioJob` cannot run simultaneously (parallel) because both are pure Python code, so you don't observe any performance improvement when you try to run them as "threads".

Answer (score 2):

> ... why I get such performance ?

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use **multiprocessing** or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

Your code runs in a non-preemptive framework, yet it never yields control, not until it exits. So another thread won't be scheduled until then. You used some thread machinery, but you may as well have written a two-line sequential function that calls `io_job()` followed by `cpu_job()`.

What you're looking for is [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Also, if you literally want to copy file trees around with tools like `rsync`, consider using `gmake -jN` or GNU parallel (`sudo apt install parallel`). Here's an example command:

```
$ find . -name '*.txt' -type f | parallel gzip -v9
```

Both make and /usr/bin/parallel let you specify number of simultaneous workers, and will continue to draw a new task from the queue each time a worker completes a task.

Comment: Well, the main Q is that why Python runtime does not release GIL while calling some shell commands for directory copy. Any Ideas?